# In this case, DO I have to make NAT GW?

Tags: amazon-web-services

i want to deploy web server on AWS.

but i want to know that Nat GW is necessary

in my diagram,

Public subnet : Application Load Balancer
Private Subnet : Web server

in this diagram, access from the Internet will be : IGW -> ALB -> WEB server

but Access from the Web server will be working like this? WEB server -> ALB -> IGW

or WEB server -> NAT GW -> IGW ?

please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Access from the Web server will be working like this? WEB server -> ALB -> IGW or WEB server -> NAT GW -> IGW ?

The NAT gateway/instace is required for your web servers in the **private subnet** if they will need to access internet. For example, to install some software, install updates or call external api. In this case you need:

```
WEB server -> NAT GW -> IGW
```

However, you could **pre-install all required software** on an instance, construct a custom AMI, and then use the AMI to launch your web-servers. In this case, you may not require internet access at all from your instances. Thus, NAT gateway would not be required.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your advice.  Then, you mean if apache server installed in my web instance , the NAT GW would not be require ?

Comment: @shpaek Yes. If its all per-installed and your web-app can operate without internet, then you don't need NAT.